# Two divs same CSS?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make two divs with the same css, something like:

```
.Navig1, .Navig11 a {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: {color: Navig Bg 1};
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Because I don't want my style code to be too long, and I need these two to look the same, but be different when hovered, and I thought this would do, but this code doesn't work.
Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
.Navig1 a, .Navig11 a {
  display:block;
  height:15px;
  width:70px;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:8px;
  line-height:15px;
  color:#FFF;
}

.Navig1 a:hover {
  /*css property*/
}

.Navig11 a:hover {
  /*other css property*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css isn't "programmable". there's no variables or methods to say "use style included in section X here".

but, you can fix it by removing the bgcolor definition from this block and creating a new one

```
.Navig1, .Navig11 a {
    ... as before ...
}

.Navig1, .Navig11 {
    background-color: #xxx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by:

```
.Navig1, .Navig11 a {
    /* Common Styles */
}

.Navig1:hover {
    /* Navig1 Specific Styles on Hover */
}

.Navig11 a:hover {
    /* Navig1 a Specific Styles on Hover */
}
```

But, as the other answerers mentioned, you have broken CSS.  What should be going on with the background color?

Comment: Sorry, I apparently didn't understand the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier to work out what you are aiming to achieve if you also provide the html. There is no need to have two CSS class's. You can use a single CSS class for the styling multiple elements on a page.

If you have multiple div containers with two set with a class called mynav:

```
<div class="mynav"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="mynav"></div>
```

Then one CSS class will effect both.

```
div.mynav a {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

div.mynav a:hover {
    /* new css */
}
```

If you wish to have a variations then you simply need to create the rule for how the element will change depending on the action you are doing.

Also consider using more than one class for a single element if needs be. Your div could be:

```
<div class="mynav someotherclass"></div>
```

You may find that for what you are doing that some simple Javascript is the best solution.